# I can't seem to rename/change some CSS classes

Tags: html, css

Ok, I'm quite new to CSS3. I have this code:

```
    <div class="Mat-Shadow-Box-Text">
    <div class="Mat-Shadow-Box-TextBleu2">

        MyText

    </div>
</div>
```

That works great. But then I want to change Mat-Shadow-Box-TextBleu2 for Mat-Shadow-Box-Text2. Same CSS class copy/pasted with 0 change (wanted to test before changing anything).

```
.Mat-Shadow-Box-Text
{
    margin: 0px 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #888;    
    behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
}

.Mat-Shadow-Box-TextBleu2
{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.Mat-Shadow-Box-Text2
{
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Now my 100$ question is: Why when I change the class name in my  tag, it doesn't work? (the border doesn't appear on the web page). Also, I tried just renaming .Mat-Shadow-Box-TextBleu2 by .Mat-Shadow-Box-Text2 (in both CSS class and DIV code) and it doesn't work either!

So, to summarize, my original code works fine, but I can't rename nor change to another class in my second DIV tag. Note that I don't have this problem with my first DIV class. I can rename .Mat-Shadow-Box-Text or point to a different class and it works just fine.

Cheers!

Comment: Works fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/gFUBu/1/ perhaps you have something else somewhere (HTML or CSS) thats affecting it ?

Comment: Well I had to refresh the web page, that's it (Why the guy who gave me the answer deleted it?). Seems like the CSS is cached by the browser.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache? This happens to me a lot, even if I set the browser to download fresh content on every visit to the page.

Comment: FWIW, you should be using more semantic class names describing what the element *is*, not what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in dev its always a good practice after changing Back-End Code, CSS, or HTML to always Ctrl+F5 to refresh your browser to force it to get everything again from the server. That seems to be what you have happening here. Its especially noticeable with CSS changes.